# Contar o total de páginas de um arquivo pdf com PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Estou tentando contar o total de páginas de um arquivo pdf, usando php.
Fiz uma busca no google e encontrei o código abaixo, que funciona para arquivos até 10mb.

Usei também a biblioteca PDFParser, mas também estou com o mesmo problema com relação à tamanho do arquivo, a diferença é que com o PDFParser é possível usar arquivos com até 41mb.

Tentei aumentar o limite de upload no php.ini, mas não obtive sucesso.
Se alguém puder me dar uma luz já agradeço muito. rs

ps: Sou iniciante em php.

```
<?php
/**
 * Esta función devuelve el número de páginas de un archivo pdf
 * Tiene que recibir la ubicación y nombre del archivo
 */
function numeroPaginasPdf($archivoPDF)
{
    $stream = fopen($archivoPDF, "r");
    $content = fread ($stream, filesize($archivoPDF));

    if(!$stream || !$content)
        return 0;

    $count = 0;

    $regex  = "/\/Count\s+(\d+)/";
    $regex2 = "/\/Page\W*(\d+)/";
    $regex3 = "/\/N\s+(\d+)/";

    if(preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches))
        $count = max($matches);

    return $count[0];
}

echo numeroPaginasPdf("docs/file1.pdf");
?>
```

**--- Atualizando ---**

*Erro exibido:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual erro é exibido?

Comment: Se puder ser fora de php: `pdfinfo docs/file1.pdf | grep Pages`

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante coloquei o erro na postagem original. ;)